# Intervalo entre comandos em C#

Tags: c#, c

Eu estou tentando criar um intervalo entre 2 comandos. Quero mostrar algo na tela para o usuario, esperar um tempo e apagar o texto.

Já pesquisei em diversos lugares e não encontrei nada. Vi coisas relacionadas a Timers, a biblioteca Timers, mas nada que me ajudasse.

```
 Console.WriteLine("Essa opção não existe");
 //comando para intervalo aqui//
 Console.Clear();
 break;
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Veja esse [exemplo](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/TaskAwait#main.cs).

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine("Essa opção não existe");
//comando para intervalo aqui
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
Console.Clear();
break;
```

Veja https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91108/how-do-i-get-my-c-sharp-program-to-sleep-for-50-msec

Comment: Seria legal se explicassem o porquê do voto negativo.

Comment: Qual o motivo da negativação dessa resposta?